# Is there a more easy and more than 6 functional code for this?

Tags: java

I was trying to do a calculator for my lesson notes and akts system.
But I couldn't do a functional option for choosable lesson and akts quantity with for loop.

```
package sa;

import java.util.Scanner;

class sA {  

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner ders = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Ders sayısını giriniz: ");
int y = ders.nextInt();

if (y == 6) {

System.out.println("Notları, gireceğiniz akts sırasıyla giriniz!");
Scanner not1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("1.not : ");
float q = not1.nextFloat();
Scanner not2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("2.not : ");
float a = not2.nextFloat();
Scanner not3 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("3.not : ");
float z = not3.nextFloat();
Scanner not4 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("4.not : ");
float w = not4.nextFloat();
Scanner not5 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("5.not : ");
float s = not5.nextFloat();
Scanner not6 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("6.not : ");
float x = not6.nextFloat();

System.out.println("Notları girdiğiniz sıra ile, akts lerini giriniz.!");
Scanner akts1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("1.akts : ");
int e = akts1.nextInt();
Scanner akts2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("2.akts : ");
int d = akts2.nextInt();
Scanner akts3 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("3.akts : ");
int c = akts3.nextInt();
Scanner akts4 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("4.akts : ");
int r = akts4.nextInt();
Scanner akts5 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("5.akts : ");
int f = akts5.nextInt();
Scanner akts6 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("6.akts : ");
int v = akts6.nextInt();

float t = q*e+a*d+z*c+w*r+s*f+x*v;
float g = t/(e+d+c+r+f+v);
System.out.println(g);
}
else {
System.out.print("Sadece 6 dersi hesaplayacak algoritma bulunmaktadır.");
}

}
}
```

Here another unfinished try.

```
package sa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class es  { 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Ders sayısını giriniz:");
    Scanner ders = new Scanner(System.in);
    int y = ders.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Notları, gireceğiniz akts sırasıyla giriniz");

    for (int i=1; i<=y; i++) {

    System.out.println(i+".not");   
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    float r = s.nextFloat();
    }

    for (int a=1; a<=y; a++) {

    System.out.println(a+".akts");          
    Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
    float e = c.nextFloat()  ;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You could read the following article to make it for others easier to answer your question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation using basic for-loops. Note that i don't speak turkish (?), so the variable names might not express their intent in a good way. Furthermore i guessed what your intention is.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Get number of courses.
System.out.print("Ders sayısını giriniz: ");
int numberOfCourses = scanner.nextInt();

float[] grades = new float[numberOfCourses];
int[] akts = new int[numberOfCourses];

// Get grades.
System.out.println("Notları, gireceğiniz akts sırasıyla giriniz!");
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%d.not : ", i + 1);
    grades[i] = scanner.nextFloat();
}

// Get akts.
System.out.println("Notları girdiğiniz sıra ile, akts lerini giriniz.!");
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("%d.akts : ", i + 1);
    akts[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}

// Calculate result.
float result = 0;
int aktsSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCourses; i++)
{
    result += grades[i] * akts[i];
    aktsSum += akts[i];
}
result /= aktsSum;

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this . That's what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

- One instance of `Scanner` is enough. And it should be close at the end.
- I can see same pieces of code, that could be moved to separate method.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Ders sayısını giriniz: ");
        int y = scan.nextInt();

        if (y == 6) {
            System.out.println("Notları, gireceğiniz akts sırasıyla giriniz!");
            float q = requestValue("1.not", scan::nextFloat);
            float a = requestValue("2.not", scan::nextFloat);
            float z = requestValue("3.not", scan::nextFloat);
            float w = requestValue("4.not", scan::nextFloat);
            float s = requestValue("5.not", scan::nextFloat);
            float x = requestValue("6.not", scan::nextFloat);

            System.out.println("Notları girdiğiniz sıra ile, akts lerini giriniz.!");
            int e = requestValue("1.akts", scan::nextInt);
            int d = requestValue("2.akts", scan::nextInt);
            int c = requestValue("2.akts", scan::nextInt);
            int r = requestValue("4.akts", scan::nextInt);
            int f = requestValue("5.akts", scan::nextInt);
            int v = requestValue("6.akts", scan::nextInt);

            float t = q * e + a * d + z * c + w * r + s * f + x * v;
            float g = t / (e + d + c + r + f + v);
            System.out.println(g);
        } else {
            System.out.print("Sadece 6 dersi hesaplayacak algoritma bulunmaktadır.");
        }
    }
}

private static <T> T requestValue(String msg, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    try {
        System.out.print(msg + " : ");
        return supplier.get();
    } finally {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to close a Scanner on System.in.

Comment: Thanks for the the guideful info , but the real question is how to do an algorithm that can be generated automatically based on the number of courses entered, which is what i really need.

Comment: Could you give more details, what this algorithm should do? input and output data, probably.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, SN42 has understood and solved what I want to do.